# How do i use existing qml file in qt creator?

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator, nokia, qml

I download some qml templeates from nokia's website. Now i want to test them. How can i import qml file into my empty project?

Templeates are here https://projects.developer.nokia.com/QMLTemplates

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have solved it.

1) Create a new Qt Quick application;

2) in the wizard choose option 'Generate a main .qml file' (first one).

3) There is two folder for each demo in qml templates. Component and example.
Then open and copy all data in main.qml under example folder and paste it to our new projects main.qml

4) Now edit main.qml in our new project -> delete 'import "../component" as Comp' and write 'import "component" as Comp' in second line.

5) Copy component folder in qml templates and paste it near to our project's main.qml file

6) Run

7)if there are extra file under example folder, copy all of them and paste near to main.qml file under our new project.

Comment: I wonder why the solution is to create a new project. There has to be a work around to add a QML file to an existing Widgets app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new Qt Quick application;
2. in the wizard choose option 'Import
   an existing .qml file' (second one)
   instead of 'Generate a main .qml
   file' (first one).
3. Click on browse button and select your QML file you that downloaded.

Comment: when i import qml file and run my project, i am having blank screen. Any of them are not working. And sometimes i have an error and debugging stops. Error is "[ copydeploymentfolders] Error 4"